# Xcode 8 Swift 3 Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

This code generates Segmentation fault: 11 error on compile:

```
class Test: UICollectionViewLayout {
    var sublayout: Sublayout?
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        sublayout?.shouldInvalidate?(forNewBounds: newBounds, currentBounds: collectionView!.bounds)
        return true
    }
}

@objc protocol Sublayout {
    @objc optional func shouldInvalidate(forNewBounds: CGRect, currentBounds: CGRect)
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, After converting my Swift 2.2 iOS app to Swift3/Xcode8 I'm getting a segfault 11. Under 2.2 the app compilied without errors or warnings so I think S3/XC8 is not ready for real work yet.

Comment: on Sept. 26, 2016

Comment: I have the same issue. Even if you could isolate what caused it, its a very bad sign about XCode 8 + Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had same problem after migrating to Swift3/Xcode8. I was able to build/run on device and simulator but on Archiving end up in **segmentation fault 11**, stack dump was pointing some protocol methods which was certainly not the cause.

But, I could still archive by setting for current Target
Swift Compiler > Code Generation > Optimisation Level > Release > None [-Onone]

[image]
I think messing up Optimisation Level is not the right thing, But until we get stable Xcode version it should be okay.